# Searching the registry with vbs to find an unknown part of the path

Tags: vbscript

I use a path to locate pieces of information that contains a guid that can change. I had the guid value hard coded, but when it changes it doesn't function. I need to discover that guid dynamically. I know a value on the other side of the guid and have a REG Query that finds the entire path, but I can't figure out how to capture that path.

Here's the REG Query:

```
REG Query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products /D /V /F "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010" /S /E
```

It returns the Value "DisplayName" and it's contents "Microsoft Office Professional Plus"

When run from a batch file it also displays the entire path that includes the elusive guid. I would like to do this from a vb script.

Answer (score 1):

Also the newer Windows Scripting Host Shell object also makes registry access easy.

```
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

wshshell.RegDelete(strName)

wshshell.RegRead(strName) 

wshshell.RegWrite(strName, anyValue [,strType])
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/293bt9hh(v=vs.84).aspx

Also WMI can access registry. Unlike both above methods it can ennumerate, so you can see what is there without having to know in advance.

```
Dim proglist()
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
ret = oReg.EnumKey(&H80000002, "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", proglist)
If err.num =0 then
   For each prog in proglist
        msgbox prog
   Next
Else
    Msgbox err.num & " " & err.description & " " & err.source
    err.clear
End If
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390387(v=vs.85).aspx

It can also check security and monitor changes to keys.

This monitors changes to Windows Uninstall key.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:root/default") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM RegistryTreeChangeEvent WHERE Hive='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' AND RootPath='SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall'")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    msgbox objReceivedEvent.GetObjectText_()
Loop
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393041(v=vs.85).aspx‎

Recursion is used to walk each node in a tree. The function calls itself every time it comes across a node. Start below program using cscript to avoid a few thousand msgboxs - `cscript //nologo c:\folder\RecurseReg.vbs`.

```
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

EnumReg "SOFTWARE\CLASSES"

Sub EnumReg(RegKey)
    On Error Resume Next
    wscript.echo "---------------------------------------"
    wscript.echo "HKLM\" & RegKey & " = " & wshshell.RegRead("HKLM\" & RegKey & "\")
    err.clear
    Dim KeyList()
    Dim ValueNameList()
    Dim ValueList()
    Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    If err.number <> 0 then 
        wscript.echo err.number
        err.clear
    End If
    ret = oReg.EnumValues(&H80000002, RegKey, ValueNameList, ValueList)
    If err.number = 0 then
       For each valuename in ValueNameList
        If valuename <> "" then
            Value = wshshell.RegRead("HKLM\" & RegKey & "\" & valuename)
            err.clear
                wscript.echo valuename & " - " & Value
        End If
       Next
    Else
        Msgbox err.num & " " & err.description & " " & err.source
        err.clear
    End If


    ret = oReg.EnumKey(&H80000002, RegKey, Keylist)
    If err.number =0 then
       For each key in keylist
            EnumReg RegKey & "\" & key
       Next
    Else
        Msgbox err.num & " " & err.description & " " & err.source
        err.clear
    End If
End Sub
```

Putting both together (this does VC 2008 Runtime which should be on all computers)

```
Dim proglist()
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
ret = oReg.EnumKey(&H80000002, "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products", proglist)
If err.num =0 then
   For each prog in proglist
'        msgbox prog
       If wshshell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\" & Prog & "\InstallProperties\DisplayName") = "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.17" then
           Msgbox "Found " & Prog 
       End If
   Next
Else
    Msgbox err.num & " " & err.description & " " & err.source
    err.clear
End If
```

**For V6 or VBA**

The registry is simple in VBA. It's is very limited and uses ini file concepts.
There's a few of them such as (from Object Browser [F2] in VBA editor)

```
 Function GetAllSettings(AppName As String, Section As String)
Member of VBA.Interaction

 Sub SaveSetting(AppName As String, Section As String, Key As String, Setting As String)
Member of VBA.Interaction

 Sub DeleteSetting(AppName As String, [Section], [Key])
Member of VBA.Interaction

 Function GetSetting(AppName As String, Section As String, Key As String, [Default]) As String
Member of VBA.Interaction
```

Also the Windows API calls can be used.

RegOpenKeyEx

The RegOpenKeyEx function opens the specified registry key.

```
LONG RegOpenKeyEx(
  HKEY hKey,         // handle to open key
  LPCTSTR lpSubKey,  // subkey name
  DWORD ulOptions,   // reserved
  REGSAM samDesired, // security access mask
  PHKEY phkResult    // handle to open key
);
```