# RegQueryValueEx for open handle

Tags: windows, vb6, registry

I have a method for opening a handle (long) to a product.
The manufacturer tells me I need to get the windows registry key information for the product.
I would like to use something like -
RegQueryValueEx
To open the existing handle and get the info such as the
VID_VVVV+PID_PPPP+6&2e3aad22&0&1&2
from the registry, is there a way to do this or is there a better solution?

Comment: May be you should post language you working with

Comment: Hi the language is vb6, but the answer does not have to be specific I can convert from any language using the api calls.  I just need the idea/technique.

Comment: In that case, what's wrong with the example code attached to the documentation for RegQueryValueEx?

Comment: The example code seems to work by opening the registry and searching for some device info in the registry.  I need to get registry information on a device that is already open and has a handle via a method from the manufacturer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026790/searching-the-registry-with-vbs-to-find-an-unknown-part-of-the-path/41027314#41027314